# Change eth0 to em1 on Scientific Linux

Tags: ethernet, scientific-linux

The aim is to standardize the Ethernet adapter type on all production servers.  One of these servers disposes an **em1**, rather than **eth0**.

Today, an attempt has been done to change it, without success. Before executing a second attempt, this conversion will be tested first.

A Vagrant box has been created and **eth0** is the current adapter.

To mimic the production setting, the eth0 needs to be changed to em1. [Biosdevname](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Consistent_Network_Device_Naming_Using_biosdevname.html) has been installed (`sudo yum install biosdevname -y`), `70-persistent-net.rules` removed (`sudo rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`), `biosdevname=1` executed and added to `/etc/grub.conf` as follows:

```
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
#          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
#          root (hd0,0)
#          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
#          initrd /initrd-[generic-]version.img
#boot=/dev/sda
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title Scientific Linux (2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_swap SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_root  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.img

biosdevname=1
```

However, once the system has been rebooted and `ifconfig` has been executed the eth0 adapter persists.

How to change `eth0` to `em1`?

Comment: Is it possible to Update your Kernel, and then enable [Predictable Network Interface Names](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/)?

Comment: em1 is belong to FreeBSD OS, are you sure your working with Linux? eth0 is belong to linux.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh Yes, the OS is Scientific Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Changing em* to eth*

**NOTE:** `em0` and `em1` are also used by RHEL & CentOS, and therefore Scientific Linux as well. They're typically used for embedded NICs that are built into the system's motherboard.

I found this blog post titled: [Solved: Renaming em1 to eth0 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6](http://www.sysarchitects.com/em1_to_eth0) which suggested adding the following to your `/etc/grub.conf`, `biosdevname=0`.

*excerpt*

> 1. I've been burned enough times to do this out of habit: make a backup of `/etc/grub.conf`, retaining SELinux info:
>
>    ```
>    $ sudo cp --preserve=context /etc/grub.conf /etc/grub.bak
>    ```
> 2. Add `biosdevname=0` to the `kernel` boot arguments in `/etc/grub.conf`.
> 3. Rename `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1` to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, changing the line:
>
>    ```
>    DEVICE="em1"
>    ```
>
>    to
>
>    ```
>    DEVICE="eth0"
>    ```
> 4. Delete `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`
> 5. Reboot.

#### Changing eth* to em*

If on the other hand you're attempting to change `eth0` to `em1`, then I believe you need to move the `biosdevname=1` from that standalonne line in your `grub.conf` file so that it's an actual parameter to the `kernel` line above.

For example:

```
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_swap SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_root  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet biosdevname=1
```

#### References

- [Migrating from Conventional Device Names to Consistent Device Names for 
  Ethernet Devices in Red Hat Enterprise Linux v6](http://linux.dell.com/files/whitepapers/consistent_network_device_naming_migration_guide_rhel_6.pdf)
- [Biosdevname - Consistent Network Device Naming](http://linux.dell.com/biosdevname/)
- [biosdevname man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/biosdevname)
- [9.6. CONSISTENT NETWORK DEVICE NAMING USING BIOSDEVNAME](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Consistent_Network_Device_Naming_Using_biosdevname.html)